# UE4 Cannot find moved files causing a crash when opening a level

Tags: unreal-4

Moved blueprints cannot be find in new location, Unreal Engine still searching them in old folder. This cause the editor to crash when trying to open a specific level.

The log error is the following:

```
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/BPI_DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/BPI_DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/BPI_DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/UI/Assets/Security/Off_Camera': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/UI/Assets/Security/Off_Camera': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
C:\Unreal Repository\ASAH\Content\Maps\S_Levels\ElectricArea.umap: Failed to load '/Game/test/Monitor/BPI_DisplayedInfo': Can't find file.
```

**Fix up Redirectors in Folder** doesn't seem to update any references, there is a way to force a full update? This happen only in a specific computer, using another computer doesn't seem to cause the same problem, even if there's no local changes.

Comment: How did you move your blueprints?

Comment: I dragged them in the final folders through Unreal Editor